# Place caption for a single figure on the right?

Tags: floats, align

I just want to know how to place a caption to the right of a single figure without modifying caption placements for the entire document, as the rightcaption (sic) package does.

The floatrow package ruins the alignment of the figure and requires a lot of technical modifiers, too.

The figure I need a caption is a stack of aligned equations. I think there should be a general way to do this now that it's in a figure environment but all similar questions are extremely specific. As mentioned, some possible solutions ended up ruining the alignment.

Here is the figure I need a caption to the right for:

```
\begin{figure}
$\begin{aligned}T&=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
c_1 & b_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
0 & c_2 & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & b_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & c_k & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & c_{n-1} & b_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
L&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
\frac{c_1}{d_1} & \ddots & \ddots & & & & \vdots\\
0 & \frac{c_2}{d_2} & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \frac{c_k}{d_k} & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & \frac{c_{n-1}}{d_{n-1}} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
U&=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & d_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & & \ddots & d_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & d_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\end{aligned}$\end{figure}
```

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{amsthm} 
\usepackage[]{amssymb} 
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}


\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3}
```

There isn't a lot of room so I just want to fill that narrow white space with something like: "Figure k: The $LU$ decomposition of an $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix"

All help is appreciated. I ma sure this is terrible programming but its me salvaging salvage, which makes it tricky to see a clean solution.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

A solution with caption package and minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{amsthm} 
\usepackage[]{amssymb} 
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}%ADDED
\usepackage{lipsum}%ADDED


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}


\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\medskip
\begin{raggedleft}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
$\begin{aligned}T&=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
c_1 & b_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
0 & c_2 & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & b_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & c_k & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & c_{n-1} & b_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
L&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
\frac{c_1}{d_1} & \ddots & \ddots & & & & \vdots\\
0 & \frac{c_2}{d_2} & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \frac{c_k}{d_k} & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & \frac{c_{n-1}}{d_{n-1}} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
U&=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & d_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & & \ddots & d_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & d_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\end{aligned}$
\end{minipage}\end{raggedleft}\medskip\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{center}
  %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{my caption here that will break in lines if needed}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice! And I dig the Lorem Ipsum, classy.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the caption to the right of the `aligned` environment, you also have to decide whether to place it at the top, middle, or bottom. Whatever you do, you risk making the caption look like it pertains to just one of the three matrices rather than to the whole, three-matrix expression.

To avoid such a risk, I'd place the caption either that the top or bottom of the `figure` environment. If you're concerned about preserving (vertical) whitespace, load the `caption` package with a smaller-than-default value for the `skip` option. (The default skip amount is `1\baselineskip`.)

I would also use a `\centering` instruction, to center the `aligned` environment. Separately, note that the `\nonumber` instructions aren't needed because `aligned` doesn't number the rows anyway.

(The left and right hand frame lines in the following screenshot are drawn by the `showframe` package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{$LU$ decomposition of an $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix $T$}
\centering
$\begin{aligned}
T&=\begin{bmatrix}
\,b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
c_1 & b_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
0 & c_2 & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & b_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & c_k & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & c_{n-1} & b_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
L&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\,\\
\frac{c_1}{d_1} & \ddots & \ddots & & & & \vdots\\
0 & \frac{c_2}{d_2} & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \frac{c_k}{d_k} & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & \frac{c_{n-1}}{d_{n-1}} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
U&=\begin{bmatrix}
\,b_1 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2 & \ddots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & a_{k-1} & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & d_k & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-2} & 0\\
\vdots & & & & \ddots & d_{n-1} & a_{n-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & d_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point, I will see if I have room. I don't see the showframe package, I will try it out

Comment: EDIT: I don't think showframe is supposed to be used as an art tool because it is outlining every object and block of text in my document, and there is some overlap. Is there another way to add bars?

Comment: @user391838 - I used the `showframe` package in my answer merely to illustrate the overall dimensions of the page, i.e., to add a sense of scale. In no way did this imply or suggest that you should be loading it in your document.